# Increasing column length in a large table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our production sever is sql server 2005, and we have a very large table of 103 Million records. We want increase length of one particular field from varchar(20) to varchar(30). Though i said its just a metadata change as its a increase in the column length my manager says he doesnt want to alter such a huge table. pl advice the best option. I am thinking to create a new column and update the new column with old column values.

I looked at many blogs and they say that the alter will impact and some say it will not impact.

Comment: Had a similar issue with converting int to bigint. Ended up saving a ton of time recreating the entire table and inserting the data into it in batches. Altering the column would have take something like 5x longer.

Comment: I think many of these processes that should be metadata only, but aren't, get improved and fixed over time. I know that some enhancements exist in SQL Server 2012, for example, where adding a non-null column can be an online operation (while a nullable column can block and update the entire table, depending on the scenario). I suspect none of these enhancements existed in SQL Server 2005. I agree with you entirely that this *should* be a metadata-only change, but I'm only posting this as a comment because I'm not *sure* that in 2005 this is the same as changing INT -> BIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it is a metadata-only operation and this is the way to go. Prove to your manager (and to yourself!) through testing that you are right.

Comment: Agreed. I could post an answer that says "it is a metadata-only operation" but how could you be sure without testing yourself?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Do you know if the declared length of a `varchar()` is stored on every data page?  Or is just the actual length stored?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Off-hand, don't know, sorry. I can't *imagine* the declared length is stored on every page, but haven't memorized page contents (and it may be different in data vs. index, and of course add columnstore and Hekaton into the mix...)

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is the actual length that is stored.

Answer (score 1):

You should test any advice first, unless from a SQL Server MVP who might actually know the details of what happens.

However, changing the `varchar` length from 20 to 30 does not affect the layout of any existing data in the table.  That is, the layout of the two variables is exactly the same.  That means that the data does not *have* to change when you alter the table.

This offers optimism that the change would be "easy".

The data page does contain some information about types -- at least the length of the type in the record.  I don't know if this includes the maximum length of a character type.  It is possible that the data pages would need to be changed.

This is a bit of pessimism.

Almost any other change will require changes to every record and/or data page.  For instance, changing from `int` to `bigint` is moving from a 4-byte field to an 8-byte field.  *All* the records are affected by this change in data layout.  Big change.

Changing from `varchar()` to either `nvarchar()` or `char()` would have the same impact.

On the other hand, changing a field from being NULLABLE to NOT NULLABLE (or vice versa) would not affect the record storage on each page.  But, that information is stored on the page in the NULLABLE flags array, so all the pages would need to be updated.

So, there is some possibility that the change would not cause any data to be rewritten.  But test on a smaller table to see what happens.

Comment: Come on now, even SQL Server MVPs can make mistakes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . No, Aaron it was not an insult.  It was a statement of fallibility on my part.  Your answers are usually spot-on.

Comment: Still seems dangerous to imply it that way - how does a reader know whether a certain MVP might actually know the details of any specific scenario, unless they also post testable code that proves it? :-)